# How to transfer music betwen Mac's?

Tags: itunes, macbook-pro, imac, music, data-transfer

I just got a new iMac and I am trying to transfer my music from my old MacBook onto my new iMac. I have all the songs in iTunes Library.
Thank You all

Answer (score 1):

If you have all the files in your iTunes library, then simply copy the library folder from its old location to ~/Music (the Music folder in your home folder) on your new account. Launch iTunes and it will detect the library.

If you wish to have your library elsewhere, place it somewhere else, then hold ⌥ as iTunes launches for the first time to let you select the library location.

With regard to the actual copying of the files, there are a number of ways you can do it. The easiest way may be to copy it over the network — AirDrop or AFP will let you copy the library, albeit pretty slowly. Alternatively, if you have an external drive big enough, you could copy it to that, then move it off onto the new Mac.

Comment: I think the main question is how to connect/see the other mac. I dont know, but I think you do :-)

Comment: @Jaqenhghar Didn't really consider it like that — thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How big is your library? You could try a DVD or USB stick/drive to copy them across.

Take a look at Apple's support page...

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4527

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [iTunes Match](https://www.apple.com/uk/itunes/itunes-match/)? This basically allows you to keep one universal library across all iTunes.apps where you register with your Apple ID.

On the downside though it costs and if it's a one-time problem it's not necessarily worth it.